# rescaling images in php automaticallly

Tags: php

I tested my site at google page speed they suggested me to serve images rescaled.

Right now for thumbnail I'm using this php

```
<?php 
if($ad_thumbnails) 
{ 
    if ($row['picfile']) $picfile = "{$datadir[adpics]}/{$row[picfile]}";

    else $picfile = "images/noimage2.png";

    $imgsize = GetThumbnailSize($picfile, $tinythumb_max_width, $tinythumb_max_height);
?>
```

What will be the best practice to rescale images automatically by modifying above code?

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of full-blown examples on how to resize images in php. Essentially you'll need the [GD2 image processing library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) enabled at your web server, and you'll need to use

1. [imagecreatefromjpeg](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) (or imagecreatefrompng or imagecreatefromgif) to create an image resource form your original file
2. [imagecreatetruecolor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php) to create a new canvas for your thumbnail (with the desired thumbnail dimensions)
3. [imagecopyresampled](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) to create the resized version of you original image on your new canvas

Here is a fully working [example](http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/).
Or, if you're lazy :) look at this drag&drop [solution](http://shiftingpixel.com/2008/03/03/smart-image-resizer/), that will do smart image resizing and caching only via URL parsing.

Comment: The drag&drop solution has an updated version here: https://github.com/lencioni/SLIR